# Plotting in degrees instead of radians

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have plotted a graph that contains a trig function. Instead of having the x-axis be in radians, I would like it to be in degrees. It's a simple task of multiplying the displayed x-axis values by `180/!pi` but I can't figure out how to do it. Let's say I'm trying to graph the cosine function as

```
q=plot(cos(x))
```

How can I change the displayed x-axis values to degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the x-values to the plotting routine:

```
x = findgen(360)
y = cos(x * !dtor)
plot, x, y
```

Or, if you are using function graphics:

```
p = plot(x, y)
```